# AWS ECS: use short DNS names instead of FQDN

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, dns, amazon-ecs, aws-fargate

I have an app in AWS ECS on fargate launch type.
For example, app contains of two services in **one internal** VPC. Their FQDNs are:
*service1.x.y.z
service2.x.y.z*

In the logs of containers I see the *service1* **can't resolve** the *service2* **short name** but it **can resolve FQDN** *service2.x.y.z*.
I use the private DNS zone in AWS, so I don't understand why can't I use **short** names?

Answer (score 0):

You should add in `/etc/resolv.conf` line(s) like:

```
search x.y.z
domainname x.y.z
```

This will set domain search to add `x.y.z` to the resolving process

Comment: Where have I to change this value? In docker containers? In Fargate I can't manage the infrastructure on which the containers run. So it's impossible.

Comment: @malcolm, you see errors in containers. So you need to change this in containers

Comment: Using awsvpc network I can't add the directive dns_search: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/task_definition_parameters.html

Comment: In the example i see:  "dnsSearchDomains": [
                ""
            ]," https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/create-task-definition.html

Comment: Yes. It means that this value is empty. I sent you a link where you can see that this directive can't be used in awsvpc network.

Comment: If its empty add record there before creating container. "dnsSearchDomains": ["string", ...]